# Set value of bean attribute on Drop Down selection: Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jstl, javabeans

I am using `JSTL` to populate drop down items, where country is an item having  `{ id, name, code }` attributes.

***My need is to get name and code for selected country.***

*for example:*

`Country{c_id, c_name, c_code}` is structure of country bean. when user selects this item I need to retrieve two values c_name, c_code.

***What I did yet:***

As I know, only one value can be assigned to `itemValue` either `c_name` or `c_code`.
I tried to populate all country and match selected country and then set to another path variable, but this also not working.

***My code is as***

```
<form:select path="selectedCountry" id="ddlCountryId">
<c:forEach items="${countries}" var="country">
    <option value="${country.countryName}" ${country.countryName == selectedCountry ? 'selected' : ''}>${country.countryName}</option>
    </c:forEach>
    </form:select>
    <input class="login_submit" type="submit" value="Login" id="btnSubmitId">

    <!-- Read country code of selected country -->
    <c:forEach var="country" items="${countries}">
        <c:out value="country"></c:out>
        <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${country.countryName==loginCreadetials.selectedCountry}">
        <input name="countryCode" type="hidden" value="${country.countryCode}"/>

        </c:when>
        </c:choose>
    </c:forEach>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the value of your option tag to a String that you can easily parse, for instance

> value="${country.countryName}:${country.countryName}"

In your controller, you can then split the string on the ':' character to retrieve your two values.